# Why does glob not work on a DFS share with command line administrator mode?

Tags: python, glob

I have a DFS network share that contains a couple of xml files, and I have written a python script that will grab my xml files using `glob`

The following is my DFS structure

```
├─ O
├──── my_path
|      ├── test1.xml
|      ├── test1.xml
|      └── test2.xml
```

The following is my code:

```
import glob

path = 'O:\\my_path\\*.xml'
files = glob.glob(path)
print 'Files found: {}'.format(len(files))
```

When I run this through the command line, everything works fine.

```
python test.py
> Files found: 3
```

However when I run this through command line administrator mode, it does not wok

```
python test.py
> Files found: 0
```

What is the cause for `glob` not working while in administrator mode and what are the solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import glob
import os

path = os.path.join('O:', 'my_path', '*.xml')
print(path)
files = glob.glob(path)
print 'Files found: {}'.format(len(files))
```